# What is the difference between <% ... %> and <%! ... %> in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am adding some more functionality to a page that has the two tags mentioned in the title. I noticed that the variable I declare in `<% ... %>` cannot be used in `<%! ... %>` and vice versa. What is the difference between the two and how can I declare variables that could be used in the two tags

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`<% ... %>` is used to embed some java code within the main `service()` method of the JSP. It is executed during the rendering of the page.

`<%! ... %>` is used to define code *outside* of the flow of the page, and therefore outside the main `service()` method. Typically, this was used to define utility methods that would be called from within a `<% ... %>` block.

Both approaches are now obsolete, however. JSP EL, JSTL and tag classes are the preferred way of doing the same thing.

Comment: i only can add that whole jsp is now deprecated since jee6. jsf - is a main view technology.

Comment: hm, is it really deprecated? I doubt that

Comment: @bozho: I guess you are referring to the comment, not the answer? @skaffman I second the notion of scriptlets being deprecated very much, whereas @foret JSPs will probably always remain appropriate for cases where action frameworks are needed because component frameworks are too resource-hungry.

Comment: @foret: JSF isn't a view technology. JSP and Facelets are. Facelets is indeed the successor of JSP when talking in JSF perspective. @foret and @Bozho: JSP is only deprecated in perspective of JSF 2.0, not of Java EE. This is literally cited in [Facelets chapter of Java EE 6 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html). @skaffman: awesome, 8 votes in JSP tag for such a simple answer? How did you do that? :o

Comment: I'm not sure if scriplets are deprecated, but they aren't the best practice since embedding Java code in your JSP file goes against the separation of presentation and business logic.

Comment: @Lotus: Scriptlets are indeed not officially deprecated when talking in JSP perspective. Its use is however officially discouraged and it should be used for quick prototyping only. Here's a cite from [Oracle JSP conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html): *JSP Scriptlets - Where possible, avoid JSP scriptlets whenever tag libraries provide equivalent functionality.*

Comment: @BalusC: Mystifying, isn't it? Related to the "bikeshed effect", I reckon.