# Difference in JSP Tutorial Scriptlets tags

Tags: jsp

Please anyone explain the difference between  **<%! ... %>** and **<% ...%>** tags

```
<%!

     String str2 = "xyz";    
     String mainMenuItems=Resources.get("sample_variyable");      

     %>     

     <% 
      String path= "samplePath"; 

     %>
```

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333138/2015318

Comment: @StarsSky : I got the answer from your link. ,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<% ... %>`  => Scriplets

`<%! ... %>` => Declaration