# Diferrence between two JSP Delimiters

Tags: java, jsp

I am fairly new to JSP but I am pretty good at Java.

In some tutorials on the internet you use

`<%`

and other times you use

`<%!`

What is the difference between these two exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between <% ... %> and <%! ... %> in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333138/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-jsp)

Comment: Related: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/) The style which you're showing there is discouraged since a decade. Perhaps you were reading heavily outdated tutorials?

Comment: I need to press a button on a website. When I press it, I will fetch some data from a database and make an Excel spreadsheet accordingly. I just didn't want to ask that kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<%!` is used for class content declarations and `<%` is used for request method body instructions.

Take a look at an example of [JSP Tutorial - Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html)

Answer (score 0):

`<%` is for normal jsp scriplets and `<%!` is for static methods and variables.